# Android setTag from Button to underscore and dash

Tags: android, xml, button

I want to set a Tag of a Button to an underscore and another to a dash.
I already tried to use `&#8211;`or without code but that does not work.
To setText it does work but not for setTag.

Do you know the two codes i need to use?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: can you explain why you want to set a tag to an "_" or "-" ??

Comment: This might be a misunderstanding of what tag is.

Comment: sure. i rebuild my own keyboard with buttons and theire i need "&#8211;" and "-" too. So if i press the right button theire is a function which reads the tag an put the tag (in this case "-" or "_") into a textview.

Comment: I want to set the Tag from a normal Button.
Like Button b = findViewById(....);
b.setTag("-");

Sorry for my bad english ;-)

Comment: just define two integers  : `public static final int DASH = 103; public static final int UNDERSCORE = 104;` , and then check the tag if it equals to the button tag and then set the Dash or the underscore directly on the textView :
`Integer tag = (Integer) btn.getTag();
if(tag == DASH)
    txtView.setText("-");
if(tag == UNDERSCORE) 
    txtView.setText("_");`

Comment: Oh no, i just took the wrong id :-( you can take the normal dash and underscore. sorry for that but thank you for your help!!